# React: CSS is not getting applied under the backtick

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I am returning a string like this from my function.

```
getCenterTextContent: (num, unit = '%') => {
    return `<span style={{fontSize: "25px"}}>${thisObject.state.num}${unit}</span><br/><br/><span style={{fontSize: "16px"}}>${thisObject.state.used}/${thisObject.state.total}</span>`;
}
```

This is creating the DOM element like this

So the CSS could not getting applied. How to deal with it.

Comment: From where you are calling this function? 
Why you are returning it as string?.

Answer (score 2):

When returning a JSX element in a function you should use () rather than ``. Your current method returns a string, which I would imagine is why the CSS is not being applied as when bundled it won't read it as JSX.

Try something like this:

```
   const getCenterTextContent = (num, unit = '%') => (
    <>
      <span style={ { fontSize: '25px' } }>
        ${thisObject.state.num}${unit}
      </span>
      <br /><br />
      <span style={ { fontSize: '16px' } }>
        ${thisObject.state.used}/${thisObject.state.total}
      </span>
    </>
  )
```

You can implicitly return from a function by using () rather than {}, so you do not need to add a full return statement. Also you need to have a parent element when returning JSX, I've used <></> which is shorthand for a React Fragment which acts a parent container without creating unnecessary HTML.

This is untested so may need some editing to get exactly what you need.

Also this assuming that your function does not have to return a string for some reason, which if it does I would recommend rethinking your method.

Comment: This is a callback function for chart, which accepts only a string literal. So this solution couldn't work for me

Comment: Which chart library? All the chart libraries I use allow JSX elements.

Comment: Another option you could try is to define the styles in a styles object like styles: {spanOne: {fontSize: 16}, spanTwo: {fontSize: 16}} and then use these inside your backticks.